# How to overload clear

Tags: matlab, octave, built-in

Overloading `clear()` with a function is easy. But how to access the workspace of the upstream function (from which `clear` was called) to clear the workspace? `builtin('clear')` will only clear the workspace of the overloaded function.

```
function ret = someFun(a,b)
    ret = a + b;
    clear
    ret = 1;
end

function clear()
    persistent boring
    if isempty(boring), boring = 0; end
    boring = boring + 1;
    builtin('clear')
end
```

Screenshot: workspace of the upstream function after calling the overloaded `clear` function
[image: workspace of the upstream function after calling the overloaded clear function]

Comment: Or you could just not overload `clear`. Perhaps you could call your function `clearLocal`. Or, given the functionality you're putting into your overloaded `clear`, maybe you could call it `clearWithCounter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`evalin`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) with the `'caller'` option. That is, replace your line

> `builtin('clear')`

by

```
evalin('caller', 'builtin(''clear'')')
```

This will *clear all variables from the workspace of the caller function*.

Should you want want to *clear all variables from the Matlab base workspace*, use the `'base'` option:

```
evalin('base', 'builtin(''clear'')')
```

Comment: A few years ago MathWorks ran an exercise where they got a bunch of new users and recorded their command-line histories, to get a feel for how people learn MATLAB. One guy started, and for some reason pretty much the _first thing_ he typed was `clear=3`. After that, his experience went downhill very quickly, and his command history included things like `clear all`, `clear clear`, `CLEAR`, `clear dammit`, `kill`, `kill matlab`. It was pretty funny.

Comment: Following that, some thought that `clear` should be made into a keyword, so you couldn't overload it. That never happened, as there are many people like OP who overload `clear`, and the backward compatibility would be a problem. But still - just don't overload `clear` for any reason, even though @Luis answer gives you a way to get round the problems. After all, what would happen if you _also_ overloaded `builtin`? As far as I know, there's literally no way to get out of that other than closing MATLAB.

Comment: @SamRoberts Very funny indeed! :-)